# Why do these two queries return different results? Trying to replace select from multiple tables with joins

Tags: sql

I'm trying to rewrite a select from multiple tables into a series of joins. I thought my solution would be equivalent but it's not returning the same data. An ideas? Here's the code:

```
/* without joins:*/
SELECT
A.column3,
D.column6,
E.column2,
I.column2,
E.column3,
F.column1,
G.column2

FROM table1 A, table2 B, table3  C, table4 D, table5 E, table6 F, table7 G table8 H  
LEFT OUTER JOIN table9 I ON H.ID = I.ID  
WHERE
A.ID = C.ID
B.ID = C.ID
D.ID = B.ID
D.ID = E.ID
E.ID = F.ID
F.ID = G.ID
E.ID = H.ID  
AND H.ISDELETED<>'T'  
AND D.ISDELETED<> 'T'

/* Here's my attempt to turn it into at series of joins: */

SELECT
D.column3,
E.column6,
I.column2,
E.column2,
F.column3,
G.column1  
FROM table1 A  
JOIN table3 C ON A.ID = C.ID  
JOIN table2  B ON B.ID = C.ID  
JOIN table4 D ON D.ID = B.ID  
JOIN table5 E ON D.ID = E.ID  
JOIN table6 F ON E.ID = F.ID  
JOIN table7 G ON F.ID = G.ID  
JOIN table8 H ON E.ID = H.ID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN table9 I ON H.ID = I.ID  
WHERE G.ISDELETED<>'T'  
AND E.ISDELETED<> 'T'
```

Comment: What engine are you using? Is this SQL Server? MySQL? etc.

Comment: A where clause removes all rows that are not included in the where clause, th ON Clause doesn't automatically exclude rows

Comment: This is SQL Server. Interesting about the where clause. I would think with an inner join, the rows would be excluded

Answer (score 0):

Change your query with the JOIN's to this and see if it matches up with your initial query:

```
SELECT
A.column3,
D.column6,
E.column2,
I.column2,
E.column3,
F.column1,
G.column2
FROM table1 A  
INNER JOIN table2 B ON A.ID = C.ID  
INNER JOIN table3 C ON B.ID = C.ID  
INNER JOIN table4 D ON D.ID = B.ID  
INNER JOIN table5 E ON D.ID = E.ID  
INNER JOIN table6 F ON E.ID = F.ID  
INNER JOIN table7 G ON F.ID = G.ID  
INNER JOIN table8 H ON E.ID = H.ID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN table9 I ON H.ID = I.ID  
WHERE
AND H.ISDELETED<>'T'  
AND D.ISDELETED<> 'T'
```

Your aliases do not match between the two queries which may throw off the results of the `JOIN`.

Also, in your first query your `WHERE` clause is:

```
AND table8.ISDELETED<>'T'  
AND table4.ISDELETED<> 'T'
```

In your bottom query, your `WHERE` clause is:

```
AND table7.ISDELETED<>'T'  
AND table5.ISDELETED<> 'T'
```

Which may also lead to difference results between the two.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, that missing comma was just a typo when I changed the names of all the tables and columns (due to some private information) for this post. Even with that comma in place, this two queries return different results. I'm not sure why this is happening since the second query should be equivalent to the first.